# retrieving timestamp record from database 

Tags: java, mysql

how to access timestamp object in resultset. i use this code

```
String displayzone  =Rs.getTimestamp("TIME_ZONE").toString();
```

it will be error....

Comment: You forgot to post the error message. There are zillion kinds of errors, which one are you talking about? Errors tell something about the cause of the problem. Ignoring errors will make the cause harder to find and understand. Not understanding the cause will make the problem harder if not impossible to solve.

Comment: @Pekka: seems to be java

Answer (score 2):

You should check that the contents of the field TIME_ZONE are truly a timestamp.
Perhaps the field is not defined as a timestamp.
Perhaps it contains a representation of the time zone, such as PDT or IST, or even -0700
In such a case, the call to getTimestamp() will recognize that it is not a timestamp and will throw an error.